# How to receive and process XML string from iphone app in php server

Tags: php, iphone, xml, post

I am beginner in web development.
I want to get the xml string from the iphone app(not browser) in the php server.
I just read documents about php about how to receive and process data from client sides, but I just get the suggestion like using $_POST to get client data.
However, they just said that $_POST is used to get html form input data from client browser.
What if it is data from iphone app? What if the data format is just NSData/NSString that forms the HTTPbody of the iphone POST request? 
What is the technique of doing this?
If okay, can someone give the php code example for me to learn more?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

if you yse `post` so you can access it via `$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do...

PHP doesn't care from what device or software data was sent. (Arguably it has no way of knowing.) PHP will put any valid HTTP POST data into the $_POST variable, regardless if it came from a browser, an iPhone app, or a carrier pidgin.

In short, if your iPhone app can send your data with an HTTP POST request, PHP will receive it in $_POST.

Comment: But, I quite don't understand why there are keys and key-values corresponding to the $_POST array variable.
If %_POST can receive any data from client, who defines the keys?

Comment: Now I see where the confusion is. By "any data" I meant "any valid POST data". Both GET and POST assume/require that any data be sent in a format like "key1=data1&key2=data2". In your case, you might send it as "xml_string=<xml...". PHP will then find it in `$_POST['xml_string']`. (Note that you should properly encode your xml string for use with POST. You'll need to do that on the iOS side, and I've no idea how - it may even do it automatically. Just search around for "iOS encode http post data".)